# Malloc crashes in recursive function

Tags: c, crash, malloc

I'm currently coding an implementation of the Burrows-Wheeler Transform which requires sorting a (large) array. Since I want to parallelize parts of the code of a recursive sort function, I decided to allocate some of the local variables in the heap (using `malloc()`) to prevent stack overflows or - at least- make the program die gracefully. That raised a whole new bunch of issues. I stripped the code down to the essential part (i.e., what causes the issues).

The following code compiles without errors. The resulting program works fine when compiled with icc, but it crashes (randomly) when compiled with gcc or tcc.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

unsigned char *block;
int *indexes, *indexes_copy;

void radixsort(int from, int to, int step)
{
    int *occurrences, *first_index_of, i;
    if((occurrences = malloc(1024)) == 0)
        exit(1);
    if((first_index_of = malloc(1024)) == 0)
        exit(1);
    memset(occurrences, 0, 1024);
    for(i = from; i < to; i++)
        occurrences[block[indexes[i] + step]]++;
    first_index_of[0] = from;
    for(i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        first_index_of[i + 1] = first_index_of[i] + occurrences[i];
    memset(occurrences, 0, 1024);
    memcpy(&indexes_copy[from], &indexes[from], 4 * (to - from));
    for(i = from; i < to; i++)
        indexes[first_index_of[block[indexes_copy[i] + step]] + occurrences[block[indexes_copy[i] + step]]++] = indexes_copy[i];
    for(i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    if(occurrences[i] > 1)
        radixsort(first_index_of[i], first_index_of[i] + occurrences[i], step + 1);
    free(occurrences);
    free(first_index_of);
}

int main(int argument_count, char *arguments[])
{
    int block_length, i;
    FILE *input_file = fopen(arguments[1], "rb");
    fseek(input_file, 0, SEEK_END);
    block_length = ftell(input_file);
    rewind(input_file);
    block = malloc(block_length);
    indexes = malloc(4 * block_length);
    indexes_copy = malloc(4 * block_length);
    fread(block, 1, block_length, input_file);
    for(i = 0; i < block_length; i++)
        indexes[i] = i;
    radixsort(0, block_length, 0);
    exit(0);
}
```

Even when the input is a very small text file (around 50 bytes), the program is **very** unstable with the latter two compilers. It works with ~50% probability. In the other cases, it crashes in the 2nd or 3rd iteration of radixsort when calling `malloc()`. It **always** crashes when the input file is bigger (around 1 MiB). Also in the 2nd or 3rd iteration...

Manually increasing the heap doesn't do any good. Either way, it shouldn't. If `malloc()` can't allocate the memory, it should return a `NULL` pointer (and not crash).

Switching back from heap to stack makes the program work with either compiler (as long as the input file is small enough).

So, what am I missing / doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if((occurrences = malloc(1024)) == 0)

make that:

if((occurrences = malloc(1024 * sizeof *occurences)) == 0)
```

But there are more problems ...

UPDATE (the 1024 = 4 * 256 seems merely stylistic ...)

```
for(i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    first_index_of[i + 1] = first_index_of[i] + occurrences[i];
```

The [i+1] index will address the array beyond its size;

Comment: And also please check for ***NULL pointer***, definitely ***not 0***, after malloc( ) call.

Comment: @wildplasser: How have I missed that? With `for(i = 0; i < 255; i++)`, everything works as it should.

Comment: @Pete Wilson: I'm confused. Aren't they the same?

Comment: No, they are not the same. Also: please work on your sizes and offsetting. A program like this should never contain any magic constants except 0 and 1 (sizeof is your friend). The for loop could also be rewritten as: "for(i = 1; i < 256; i++) first_index_of[i] = first_index_of[i-1] + occurrences[i-1];" That makes it easyer to verify that indexing stays within [0,256)

Comment: @PeteWilson: Comparing to 0 and comparing to NULL are exactly equivalent.  0 is a *null pointer constant*; so is whatever `NULL` expands to.

Comment: @wildplasser: Yes, they're the same.  A null pointer's representation isn't necessarily all-bits-zero, but a constant `0` is a *null pointer conatant*` and will convert to a null pointer in this context.  (You could have problems if there's no `#include <stdlib.h>` for the declaration of `malloc`, but the `#include` is required anyway.)

Comment: Though `NULL` is more explicit and IMHO better style.

Comment: "is whatever NULL expands to" - to be precise, `0` converted to a pointer type is the same as `NULL` converted to that pointer type. The difference is that `0` has type `int`, whereas `NULL` might have any integer type or `void*`. Commonly it's `((void*)0)` or similar. Personally I don't bother with `NULL` in C, since it's designed to "explicitly" mean a pointer, but is not guaranteed actually to be one, only to convert to one. `0` works just as well for that, and you won't accidentally pass it without casting into a varargs function that requires a pointer.